# Reference javascript object in its variables when declaring it

Tags: javascript

I have an object that is defined like this:

```
function company(announcementID, callback){
    this.url = 'https://poit.bolagsverket.se/poit/PublikSokKungorelse.do?method=presenteraKungorelse&diarienummer_presentera='+announcementID;
    self = this
    GM_xmlhttpRequest({
        method: "GET",
        url: this.url,
        onload: function(data) {
            self.data = data;
            callback();
        }
    })
}
```

on the callback, I wish to reference another method for that object called "callbacktest", I'm trying to do it like this?

```
    var mycompany = new company(announcementID, callbacktest);
```

if I would do it with an anonymous function, I would have written mycompany.callbacktest() but how do I reference "mycompany" from within its variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until the reference is returned from the constructor to `mycompany`, you really can't access it for an argument.

So, I would say the "*anonymous function*" you alluded to is a good way to accomplish this as it will have access to the variable, which will have the reference:

```
var mycompany = new company(announcementID, function () {
    mycompany.callbacktest();
});
```

Or, maybe move the request work and `callback` to a method.

```
function company(announcementID){
    this.url = 'https://poit.bolagsverket.se/poit/PublikSokKungorelse.do?method=presenteraKungorelse&diarienummer_presentera='+announcementID;
}

company.prototype.request = function (callback) {
    var self = this;
    GM_xmlhttpRequest({
        method: "GET",
        url: this.url,
        onload: function(data) {
            self.data = data;
            callback();
            // or: callback.call(self);
        }
    })
};

company.prototype.callbacktest = function (...) { ... };

// ...

var mycompany = new company(announcementID);
mycompany.request(mycompany.callbacktest);
```

Note: You may need to [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the method when passing it to `.request()`.

```
mycompany.request(mycompany.callbacktest.bind(mycompany));
```

Comment: and add the httpRequest to a method

Comment: I just tried your second suggestion! It seems to work alltough  console.log(this) does not return mycompany inside callbacktest, but rather the window-object

Comment: @KristofferNolgren I edited in a "Note" at the end that may be relevant to that. Did you see that yet? It may also benefit from mixing in [Antti's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18207902/15031).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have the constructed company as the `this` in callback, you can do so by:

```
// instead of callback(); do:
callback.call(self);
```

Comment: Why is this downwoted?

Comment: Ok thanks for downvote; he says he would want to say "mycompany.callbacktest()" but can't.